# Laravel NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: laravel

Am new to laravel and found it very difficult to devise a code for uploading CSV file to MySQL...I have done the following coding...

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('items.items');
}

public function import(Request $request)
{
    if($request->file('imported-file'))
    {
        $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

        if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
        {
            $data = $data->toArray();
            for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            {
                $dataImported[] = $data[$i];
            }
        }
        Inventory::insert($dataImported);
    }
    return back();
}
```

In View:

```
<form action="{{route('items.import')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="file" name="imported-file"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Import</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Routes.php

> Route::get('items', 'ItemController@index');
>
> Route::post('items/import',[ 'uses' => 'ItemController@import', 'as'
>   => 'items.import'] );

This gives me an error called NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

All what I can understand that there is some method or controller is missing in my code but could not figured out what is that...can anyone please help me here I am really got stuck into this for quiet a long time.

Comment: @admcfajn yes as its coming from maatwebsite/excel git repository..

Answer (score 0):

First try using

```
Route::get('items/import',[ 'uses' => 'ItemController@import', 'as' => 'items.import'] );
```

if the items/import is accessed then

```
Route::any('items/import',[ 'uses' => 'ItemController@import', 'as' => 'items.import'] );
```

Other than this you might want to use:

`<form action="/items/import" method="post"` and keep the post in route

instead of

```
<form action="{{route('items.import')}}" method="post"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define just simple route

```
Route::any('items/import',ItemController@import);
```

and make sure that you have to add a dependency in the controller. is it there? Like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this your form like:

```
<form action="{{ url('items/import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**And** your import function like:

```
use Redirect;

public function import(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->file('imported-file'))
      {
                $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();

            if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
      {
        $data = $data->toArray();
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        {
          $dataImported[] = $data[$i];
        }
            }
      Inventory::insert($dataImported);
        }
        return redirect()->route('items.import');
  }
```

**Updated answer**

```
    Route::get('items', 'ItemController@index')->name('items');

    Route::post('items/import', 'ItemController@import')->name('items.import');

public function import(Request $request)
        {
          if($request->file('imported-file'))
          {
                    $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
                    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
                })->get();

                if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
          {
            $data = $data->toArray();
            for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            {
              $dataImported[] = $data[$i];
            }
                }
          Inventory::insert($dataImported);
            }
            return redirect()->route('items.import');
      }
```

Comment: What would be my route.php?

Comment: It gives me this error...Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: I have added the following lines in the route.php..
Route::get('items', 'ItemController@index')->name('items');

Route::post('items/import', 'ItemController@import')->name('items.import');

Comment: On adding those lines in route.php the whole application is getting the follwoing error...Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: @user3305327: Which laravel version  are you use?

Comment: and now am getting this error...MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 0):

run those command and then refres page

1.`php artisan route:clear`

2.`php artisan cache:clear`

3.`composer dumpautoload`

and last one is

4.`composer update`